# UITableView Footer is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDny9.png) The Controller is UIViewController.

I have a `UIScrollView` in `UIViewController`. A Tableview is added as a subview upon the scrollview. The Scroll view content size is bigger than the screen size. There is a footer in the Tableview. When I am reloading the Tableview first time with the data then the Footer is not displaying but when I started the scroll then the footer is not displaying properly.

Could you please guide me, how to make this resolve.

Thanks

Comment: add picture.Hard to visualize.

Comment: if you are using auto layout set height constraint for tableview and update scrollview content size.you need to set observer for tableview.

Comment: I am not using Autolayout here.

Comment: set the content size of scrollview in viewWillLayoutSubviews method

Comment: give full size screenshot , plz . .

Comment: is your view controller embedded in navigation controll  ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's wrong practise to add UItableview inside scrollview, because tableview already has scrollview underneath it and will adjust the content size of tableview automatically depending on the content you add.

Can you please let me know the reason why you have added tableview inside scrollview?

Remove tableview from scorllview and everything show work fine.